# Why the following field isn't an ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, ordered-fields

Consider the field 
$$F = \{(a, b) | a, b \in \mathbb{R}\},$$ 
with two operations:

$$(a, b) + (c, d) = (a + c, b + d),$$

$$(a, b) · (c, d) = (ac − bd, ad + bc).$$

Prove that $F$ isn't an ordered field.

I've been trying to find ways this contradicts properties of ordered field, but couldn't find any. I'm also having difficulty defining what $(a,b) > (c,d)$ means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you recognize that this is just a very familiar field in disguise?

In any case, note that $(1, 0)$ is the unity of the field, and $(-1, 0)$ is its opposite. Note that $(0, 1)^{2} = (-1, 0)$.

Comment: Do you mean that because (0,1)^2 is smaller than 0, then it violates the property that x^2>=0? How did you determine that (-1,0)<0?

Comment: I am appealing to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Positive_cone).